# Microsoft SQL Server delete table and temp table "Bug" Question

Tags: sql-server

I ran the following code on an MS SERVER 2016.

```
SELECT ID + 100, 
DESCRIPTION,
TEMPLATETYPE,
USERID,
FACILITY,
SPECIALTY,
TEMPLATE
INTO FIELDTEMPLATES_TEMP
FROM FIELDTEMPLATES

UPDATE FIELDTEMPLATES_TEMP
SET USERID = 'sysdba'

UPDATE FIELDTEMPLATES_TEMP
SET FACILITY = NULL

SELECT ID,
DESCRIPTION,
TEMPLATETYPE,
USERID,
FACILITY,
SPECIALTY,
TEMPLATE
INTO FIELDTEMPLATES
FROM FIELDTEMPLATES_TEMP

SELECT ID,
DESCRIPTION,
TEMPLATETYPE,
USERID,
FACILITY,
SPECIALTY,
TEMPLATE
FROM FIELDTEMPLATES

DROP FIELDTEMPLATES_TEMP
```

And the code seemed to have worked but then MS Server dropped the Temp table and the base table disappeared. Now the script was only intended to obviously drop the temp table only and people freaked out when the original table disappeared.

Does anyone have any idea what happened or what could cause this? As far as I know, there were no triggers associated with this and I can't find anything other than the opposite, tables not deleting in Microsofts help center.

Any knowledge to prevent this from happening again would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Prevent *what*? There are no temporary tables in this code, only a regular table with a suffix. SQL Server won't drop tables unless you explicitly ask for it. Unless they were created in the `temp` database which, as the name suggests, is temporary

Comment: By base table, do you mean the `FIELDTEMPLATES` source table was dropped after running the script? The [default trace](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/12/sql-server-who-dropped-table-or-database/) might still have information on the table drop if you act quickly. It was likely dropped by other code/session.

Comment: How did you create those tables? What you claim is beyond extraordinary - *millions of people* would have noticed this decades ago if there were any such issues. You'll have to post a script that can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dan probably guessed what the *actual* problem is. This isnt' a temporary table, it's a plain old table, visible to anyone. If other parts of the code or other sessions treat those two tables as if they were temporary ones, perhaps some *other* code tried to create `FIELDTEMPLATES` and then deleted it. If the application started as a dekstop app, perhaps the code assumes it has full ownership of the tables

Comment: This code may not have run successfully. Your forth query selects `INTO FIELDTEMPLATES` which is your base table and exists at that point. You cannot select `into` an existing table.

Comment: Indeed, none of the tables in that script are "temporary" in terms of SQL Server. Actual temporary tables are created in `tempdb` as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned. You create them by preceeding the object name with a hash (`#`). A single `#` means the table only has a scope of the connection using it; where as `##` means that any connection can access it. For both types they are dropped as soon as the connection that created them closes (or it is no longer in use if it was at the time the connection closes with the latter). You *can* also create objects in `tempdb`, which are lost at restart.

Comment: To add to what GSerg said, perhaps there's a TRY/CATCH block on the server or client code that tried to drop those "temporary" tables in case of error. Once that script failed, the error handling code removed the tables

Comment: I want to say thank you for all the help. I did miss state the tables. I signed in as admin. The base table Fieldtemplates was already in the system. What I was asked to do was to copy the data in the table into the same table with user ID SYSDBA and Facility Null. Now I am used to Oracle not MS SQL and used what I term as a temp table(which I mean one I create and delete all in the same script) and used the select into and updates to accomplish the overall goal. The issue was that it completely wiped out the base table when the drop statement ran which was confusing. I never saw this before.

Comment: I am not sure if it is relative or related, I was removed in to the server performing the work when I was bumped out as code was initiating by an individual with superior admin rights to mine, would this have affected it in any way? As the issue occurred and was noted after the ability to log back in.

Comment: Getting bumped out wouldn't have mattered. Even without transaction handling, if your connection do the database was broken, whatever wasn't committed would be rolled back. There's nothing in the code you provided that would drop both tables and, as mentioned previously, that would be a serious bug that literally millions of people would have noticed. Also as mentioned, the code you provided is not logically valid due to trying to select into an existing table, which would throw an error before it even got to the DROP. Something else had to have run against the database for both to drop.